# How do I fix an unexpected inconsistency on my Linux partition?

Tags: 14.04, filesystem

I'm receiving the following error on boot:

```
/dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY in ubuntu 16.04
```

`fsck /dev/sda6` is not working. How do I fix things?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

To manually perform a file system check on your Ubuntu disk...

- boot to the GRUB menu (where you select which OS to start)
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /` # check the root file system
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda6` # just in case sda6 and / are different
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`